# Inserting row data key into database from jQuery DataTables using Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application and I want to insert some records in the database. In the database model I have 2 tables. One that contains general info, and the other one that contains the values of each record on the first table for each month. The jQuery DataTable lists the names of all the records in table 1. It also has 3 input fields to insert to the other table. The problem is I can't figure out how to get the ID of the record from the first database table, directly from the DataTable.

[image: The DataTable]

This is the code of the jQuery DataTable:

```
{ data: 'value_code', name: 'value_code' },
{ data: 'id', name: 'id'},
{ data: 'value_workload', name: 'value_workload' },
{
    className: '',
    orderable: false,
    data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
       return '<input name="month[]" data-name"month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />'
    }
},
{
    className: '',
    orderable: false,
    data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
       return '<input name="value[]" data-name"value-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control" type="number" />'
    }
},
{
    className: '',
    orderable: false,
    data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
    return '<input name="comment[]" data-name"comment-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control" type="text" />'
    }
},
```

In my model have:

```
public function values(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Values');
}
```

in the `Reports.php` model and in the `Values.php`

```
public function reports(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reports');
}
```

In the `ReportsController.php` i have:

```
public function store(Request $request, Value $value)
{

    $months = $request->get('month');
    $comments = $request->get('comment');
    $values = $request->get('value');
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $workload = $request->get('value_workload');

    // initialize return array
    $reports = [];
    // assumes arrays have same number of entries
    foreach($months as $key => $month) {
        $comment = $comments[$key];
        $value = $values[$key];
        // determine number of filled inputs
        $numFilled = !empty($month) + !empty($comment) + !empty($value);
        // if at least two inputs filled
        if ($numFilled >= 2) {
            $date = explode('-', $month);
            $year = isset($date[0]) ? $date[0] : '';
            $month = isset($date[1]) ? $date[1] : '';
            $reports[] = $value->reports()->create([
                'value_id' => $id,
                'value_workload' => $workload,
                'month' => $month,
                'year' => $year,
                'value' => $value,
                'comment' => $comment
            ]);
        }
    }
    return $reports; // this is what has been input! YAY!
}
```

As i said the problem is on linking the records from the 2 database tables with the foreign key. I can't seem to get it no matter what i try.
All the help or hints are appreciated.

**Edit:**

One way of doing this is adding those row details into a input field but I don't know (tried and failed) how to do it with jQuery DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and i'm posting it here so anyone else facing the same problem can find it.

At jQuery DataTable initialization code, after:

```
columns:[
   { data: 'value_code', name: 'value_code' },
   { data: 'id', name: 'id'},
   { data: 'value_workload', name: 'value_workload' },
   {
       className: '',
       orderable: false,
       data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
           return '<input name="month[]" data-name"month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />'
       }
   },
   {
       className: '',
       orderable: false,
       data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
           return '<input name="value[]" data-name"value-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control" type="number" />'
       }
   },
   {
       className: '',
       orderable: false,
       data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
           return '<input name="comment[]" data-name"comment-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control" type="text" />'
       }
   }]
```

add the following

```
"columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": [1],
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          return '<input type="text" name="id[]" data-name"id-' + meta.row + '" class="inactive" value="'+data+'" disabled/>';
      }
   }
```

and it will work just fine.